# Return Mean Max with Different Group value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, etl

I want to get min value by two group levels, for example min value group by quarter and min value group by quarter by store. And seeking if there is other way to do instead of table joining as i think table joining is slow.

for example i have a data-set

```
   Date       Quarter  Year Store Price     Sales Unit
   1-1-2020    Q1      2020   A     1            1
   31-1-2020   Q1      2020   A     3            0
   1-2-2020    Q1      2020   B     2            1
   1-5-2020    Q2      2020   A     4            3
   1-9-2020    Q4      2020   B     5            9
```

Expected result

```
    Date       Quarter Year  Store  Price  Sales Unit   Min by Quarter    Min by Quarter by Store
   1-1-2020    Q1      2020   A     1            1      1  (1,3,2 in Q1)    1  (1,3 in store A and Q1)
   31-1-2020   Q1      2020   A     3            0      1                   1
   1-2-2020    Q1      2020   B     2            1      1                   2
   1-5-2020    Q2      2020   A     4            3      4                   4 
   1-9-2020    Q4      2020   B     5            9      5                   5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `min` for new column filled aggregate values per groups:

```
df['Min by Quarter'] = df.groupby('Quarter')['Price'].transform('min')
df['Min by Quarter by Store'] = df.groupby(['Quarter', 'Store'])['Price'].transform('min')
print (df)
        Date Quarter  Year Store  Price  Sales Unit  Min by Quarter  \
0   1-1-2020      Q1  2020     A      1           1               1   
1  31-1-2020      Q1  2020     A      3           0               1   
2   1-2-2020      Q1  2020     B      2           1               1   
3   1-5-2020      Q2  2020     A      4           3               4   
4   1-9-2020      Q4  2020     B      5           9               5   

   Min by Quarter by Store  
0                        1  
1                        1  
2                        2  
3                        4  
4                        5
```